# Boolean algebra: confusion regarding the distributive law

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

I know how the distributive law is defined in propositional logic:

$a \vee (b \wedge c) = (a \vee b) \wedge (a \vee c)$

In boolean algebra, conjunction (and) translates to boolean products, while disjunction (or) translates to boolean sums, and my book defines the distributive law as follows:

$a + bc = (a + b)(a + c)$

I'm a bit confused when this law is applied, though. They presented a problem in which one of the steps was:

$y + zy$

And they translated this to:

$y(1 + z)$

Now, in standard algebra, this is pretty straightforward, but it doesn't seem to make sense in terms of the definition they provided. In this case, $y = a = c$ and $z = b$, so by the definition above:

$y + zy = (y + z)(y + y)$

By the idempotent law, this should be:

$y(y + z)$

Could someone please help clarify this? I'm very confused.

Comment: Well, if $y = 0$ then $y(y+ z) = 0*(y+z) = 0 = y = 0*(1+z) = y(1+z)$ and if $y = 1$ then $y(y+z) = y(1+z)$ so....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are all equivalent:

$$y(y+z)=yy+yz=y+yz=y(1+z)$$

since

$$yy=y$$

Comment: Oh, I see. This makes a bit more sense now. Thank you!

Comment: @AleksandrH You're welcome! :)